# UIB-DatePicker-popup customize text that is displayed in textbox

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a uib-datepicker-popup control that I want to function normally, except with 1 difference and I'm not sure if/how to accomplish this 1 change.  My control looks like the following:

```
<input type="text"
       class="form-control"
       uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy"
       ng-model="vm.selectedDate"
       ng-click="vm.toggleCalendar()"
       is-open="vm.datepickerOpen"
       datepicker-template-url="{{vm.pickerHtmlSource}}"
       datepicker-popup-template-url="{{vm.popupHtmlSource}}"
       datepicker-options="vm.dateOptions"
       close-text="Close"
       change-month="vm.changeMonth($month, $year)"/>
```

What I want is when a date is picked it currently displayed the date, i.e. 06/22/2016.  What I want to be able to do is change what is displayed in the textbox.  There are 3 different things that I would like to display based on some other properties in the application.  I want to display the date, like it is now, 06/22/2016.  Or I want to display W/E 6/25/2016, which is the Week Ending date, which will typically be Sunday, but sometime it might be a different day (which I know based on some other data that I have loaded).  The last thing that I want to display is custom fiscal month label, which I again would now based on other data that I have loaded, so it would be similar to the Week Ending on.

I did some more investigating into this and there is a service called uibDateParser that controls what is displayed in the textbox.  They have an array for formatCodeToRegex methods.  If I modify this code I can control what gets printed out, but I don't want to change that file because then I would have to remember to change it anytime I updated.  So is there a way I can update the below without affecting the main file.

```
.service('uibDateParser', ['$log', '$locale', 'dateFilter', 'orderByFilter', function($log, $locale, dateFilter, orderByFilter) {
  // Pulled from https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/format/requote.js
  var SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_REGEXP = /[\\\^\$\*\+\?\|\[\]\(\)\.\{\}]/g;

  var localeId;
  var formatCodeToRegex;

  this.init = function() {
    localeId = $locale.id;

    this.parsers = {};
    this.formatters = {};

    formatCodeToRegex = [
      {
        key: 'yyyy',
        regex: '\\d{4}',
        apply: function(value) { this.year = +value; },
        formatter: function(date) {
          var _date = new Date();
          _date.setFullYear(Math.abs(date.getFullYear()));
          return dateFilter(_date, 'yyyy');
        }
      },
   ]
  };
...
}
```

What I have done to make it the smallest change is in the init function about I added the following line

```
this.formatCodeToRegex = formatCodeToRegex;
```

With this line in there I can then use the following in my class (it is written in TypeScript, but you should be able to get the idea without knowing about TypeScript) obviously this is just hardcoded to bye right now and I will adjust to real code.

```
    static $inject = ['$scope', '$q', '$location', 'uibDateParser'];
    constructor($scope: IOsdatepickerDirectiveControllerScope, $q: ng.IQService, $location: ng.ILocationService, uibDateParser: any) {
        super($scope, $q, $location);

        uibDateParser.formatCodeToRegex.push({
            key: 'WEND',
            regex: '.*',
            apply(value) {

            },
            formatter(date) {
                return 'Bye';
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't understand you Paul. Upload screenshot with what is wrong? I can't see any date formats in date-picker at all, and display format you are providing by yourself uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy"

Comment: it seems you want to put some custom string in the datepicker input box. You can't just have some random string because the ng-model expects a date object, but you can probably use a different format from the available formats to achieve this, or you can probably override the toString method of your particular date object to display it how you want

Comment: OR you can have these strings (W/E and fiscal year) in new controls and place them around the date picker.

Comment: gaurav5430 what you are explaining is exactly what I'm talking about.  How would I go about overriding the toString of the date object.  I can't use the and standard date formats to achieve what I'm looking for because what I'm trying to achieve is actually based on the fiscal calendar for my company, so no standard format will work.